# travis not installing composer dependencies

Tags: symfony, composer-php, travis-ci

All of my Travis builds failed because my `composer` dependencies are not installed (the `before_script` step seems skipped).

Here is my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: php
sudo: required
php:
    - 5.4

before_script:
    - composer install --dev

script:
    - phpunit -c app
```

I'm sure this is something I missed but I'm not sure what. [This](https://api.travis-ci.org/jobs/99753313/log.txt?deansi=true) is my last build log.

Comment: are you sure 'composer' is installed on travis VM ? and what does travis tells you in the online log ?

Comment: i enclosed the log as u can see .... composer is an alias for composer.phar at travis

Comment: It asks you to execute `/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.5/bin/composer self-update`.  And it seems that before script isn't called :/ place composer install --dev in the script to see if it's before_script who fails, or if it's the lack of updated composer that produces that.

Comment: problem was utf8 related..

Comment: could you explain more precisely ?

Comment: See the answer i checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your repository and the issue is the encoding of your Travis configuration file. Changing the encoding (removing the BOM) makes it work: https://travis-ci.org/huitiemesens/functionnal-test-generator/builds/99764001

Answer (score -1):

Change the configuration to install your dependencies in the `install` step:

```
# ...

install:
    - composer install

# ...
```

Comment: That's better, but not related to the problem.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I took a look at your repositry and the issue is the encoding of your Travis configuration file. Changing the encoding makes it work: https://travis-ci.org/huitiemesens/functionnal-test-generator/builds/99764001

Comment: i merge pull request and that worked, thx a lot , but wow utf8 no bom to be read by a script.... bad issue

Comment: @xabbuh put an answer so i validate it

Comment: Done, sorry for the confusion. I should have looked at your repository before my first answer.